# Write a Stringformated Hex Block to registry in Binary value

Tags: c#, registry, registrykey

I am really get stucked with something. 
I have a string which includes hex values:

> string creatorSid =
>   @"01,05,00,00,00,00,00,05,15,00,00,00,10,b1,9d,4a,7a,85,7b,05,
>                                    79,05,b3,7c,ee,03,00,00";

I want to put that into the registrykey which requires binary values.

I tried this:

> key.SetValue("creatorSID", creatorSid  , RegistryValueKind.Binary);

But I got error message that it can not be converted.

Here is the complete Code so far:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String printerName = "Naked";
        RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers\" + printerName , true);


        string security = "01,00,0c,80,d0,00,00,00,dc,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,00,00,02," +
                           "00,bc,00,07,00,00,00,00,00,24,00,0c,00,0f,00,01,05,00,00,00,00,00,05,15,00," +
                            "00,00,10,b1,9d,4a,7a,85,7b,05,79,05,b3,7c,ee,03,00,00,00,09,24,00,30,00,0f," +
                            "00,01,05,00,00,00,00,00,05,15,00,00,00,10,b1,9d,4a,7a,85,7b,05,79,05,b3,7c," +
                            "ee,03,00,00,00,09,14,00,00,00,00,10,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,00,00," +
                            "00,14,00,08,00,02,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,0a,14,00,00,00," +
                            "00,20,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,18,00,0c,00,0f,00,01,02,00," +
                            "00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,00,0b,18,00,00,00,00,10,01,02,00,00," +
                            "00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,12,00,00,00,01," +
                            "01,00,00,00,00,00,05,12,00,00,00";



        var data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(security);

        try
        {
             key.SetValue("Security", data, RegistryValueKind.Binary);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(exc.StackTrace);
        }



    }
}
```

It`s writing the entry now, but the values are changed. If i check the key there is: "30 00 31 00 ....." in it. But it must be: "01 00 0c 80....." (must be exactly the value from the string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have string, you've to use `RegistryValueKind.String`.

```
key.SetValue("creatorSID", creatorSid , RegistryValueKind.String);
```

If at all you need to use `RegistryValueKind.Binary`, you need to convert the `string` to `byte[]` and store it as `byte[]`.

To store the value:

```
var data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(creatorSid);
key.SetValue("creatorSID", data, RegistryValueKind.Binary);
```

To get the value back:

```
var data = (byte[])key.GetValue("creatorSID");
if (data != null)
{
    string creatorSID = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data);
}
```

[RegistryKey.SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k23f0345%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**Edit:** It seems you don't need to convert the `,` character as byte. Try the following.

To store the value:

```
var data = security.Split(',')
    .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(x, 16))
    .ToArray();
key.SetValue("creatorSID", data, RegistryValueKind.Binary);
```

To get the value back:

```
var data = (byte[])key.GetValue("creatorSID");
if (data != null)
{
    string creatorSID = string.Join(",", data.Select(x => x.ToString("x2")).ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, but I have to store it as REG_BINARY entry. Is there an easy way to convert the string block to Byte?

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. If I try that, I get "unhandled exception" Input String was not in a correct format.

Comment: @AndreDontsch Post your current code which throws that exception with the exception message and mention which line throws it. Edit your question with this info,